# Law of large numbers application

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I came around this question on the web:

There are two maternity hospitals in a town with 50 and 500 beds. Given full occupancy on a particular day, which of these hospitals is more likely to have equal no of boys and girls given probability of boys = probability of girls ? ‪

What would the answer intuitively be by Law Of Large Numbers? How should the statement be positioned for Law Of Large Numbers to work?

Am I right to conclude that expected number of boys are 25 and 250 respectively in the hospitals? Also I don't seem to understand the application of law of large numbers here, can someone shed light on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The 50-bed hospital is far more likely to have equal numbers of boys and girls.

The law of large numbers tells us that the proportion of boys is likely to approach 0.5 more and more closely as the number of beds becomes larger and larger. By that, I mean that $actual \> proportion\> of \>boys \rightarrow 0.5$, or in other words, $\frac{actual \> proportion\> of \>boys}{0.5}\rightarrow 1$. It tells us nothing about the probability that the proportion of boys is exactly 0.5, which falls as the number of beds increases. It doesn't even tell us that the expected difference between the number of boys and half of the total number of babies decreases. In fact that expected difference increases.

You are right to think that the expected proportion of boys is 0.5 in both cases. Indeed it would be 0.5 even if the number of beds were odd.

Answer (score 1):

The Law of Large Numbers tells us that the Average behavior tends to the Expected Value as the sample size increases, but it doesn't help you compute exact values.  Indeed, for large samples, the probability of getting any exactly specified ratio tends to $0$.  In this case we can compute everything precisely.

This is a binomial process, with $2n$ trials and $p=\frac 12$. Specifically, you are interested in $n=25,250$. We see that the probability of a tie is $$\psi(n)=\binom {2n}n\times \frac 1{2^{2n}}$$

The numbers are small enough to compute both.  We get $$\psi(25)=0.112275173,\;\psi(250)=0.035664646$$

Comment: Shouldn't the expected value be 0.5 and by increasing n the value should tend towards 0.5? It isn't happening here

Comment: @uzumaki: there is a difference between a) the number of boys being close to half the number of births and b) the proportion of births which are boys being close to a half: the standard deviation of the number of boys is $\sigma \sqrt{n}$  while the standard deviation of the proportion of boys is $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ and these behave differently when $n$ increases. (If the probability of a boy is $\frac12$ then $\sigma=\frac12$)

Comment: The expected ratio is indeed $\frac 12$, but that does not mean that the probability of getting exactly $\frac 12$ goes up, or even that it is positive (though it is here).  If you toss a fair coin a trillion and one times, then the probability that exactly $\frac 12$ of the tosses is $H$ is $0$ (as the sample size is odd).  This does not contradict the Law of Large Numbers.

Comment: In the limit, we get a normal distribution centered at $\frac 12$...but in that case the probability of getting any exactly specified value is $0$ (a general property of continuous distributions).

Comment: To compare $\psi(25)$ and $\psi(250)$ without actually computing them (and to generalize the result to every pair of numbers $n<k$), note that $\psi(n+1)=\frac{2n+1}{2(n+1)}\psi(n)<\psi(n)$ for every $n$.